# Login Function PHP SHA1

Tags: php, security

i'm a beginner in PHP and on StackOverflow !
I tried to create a login function for my app, but this does'nt seem to work...

```
function login($user, $password)
{
    $db = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'raspberry', 'extranet');
    $db->set_charset('utf8');
    $token = '';
    if (isset($user) && isset($password) && !isset($_SESSION))
    {
        $query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE USERNAME = ? AND PASSWORD = ?');
        $query->bind_param($user, $password);
        $res = $query->execute();
        if (mysqli_num_rows($res) != 0)
        {
            $_SESSION['user'] = $user;

            $token = rand(85765, 650000);
            $query = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO tokens VALUES(null, ?, ?);');
            $query->bind_param($user, $token);
            $query->execute();

            $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
        } else {
            $_SESSION['token'] = 0;
        }

        return $_SESSION['token'];
    } else if (isset($_SESSION['token']) && $_SESSION['token'] != 0 && isset($_SESSION['user']))
    {
        $query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM tokens WHERE USERNAME = ? AND TOKEN = ?');
        $query->bind_param($_SESSION['user'], $_SESSION['token']);
        $res = $query->execute();
        if (mysqli_num_rows != 0)
        {
            return true;
        } else
        {
            return false;
        }
    } else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Can you tell me what's the problem. ?
thks !
P-S: excuse me for my english level i'm just a french

Comment: What is the error message and what did you tried already?

Comment: Do ***NOT*** hash passwords using SHA1, it is fundamentally broken for that purpose. Use: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php

Comment: I 'd also suggest to not post passwords... :) (`mysqli(...)`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> $query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE USERNAME = ? AND PASSWORD = ?');
> $query->bind_param($user, $password);
> ```

You're storing plaintext passwords here. Look at PHP's [password hashing features](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.password.php).

> `$token = rand(85765, 650000);`

I'm pretty sure your entire token system is unnecessary, but even if it weren't, [don't use `rand()`](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/07/how-safely-generate-random-strings-and-integers-in-php).

Comment: Thanks ! I tried to find some informations about sessions tokens but it's quite complex ! So , in which case do we use tokens ?

Comment: PHP does this for you. Unless you're thinking long-term authentication. Check out [Gatekeeper](https://github.com/psecio/gatekeeper).